# Why button keep blinking after I add sound?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem regarding my button in my Flash project. I add sound inside the button and when user roll over the button, the sound will function. It works well with other buttons inside the project. But there is problem with one button that has motion tween inside it. When user roll over for once, it works well. But when user left the mouse on the button, it keep blinking and the sound repeats. I dont know why, maybe got any relation to the motion tween added inside the button(?)

I am using Adobe Flash CS6.
 Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Show the code your using, or post your .fla,  or both.   Sounds like you're just missing a `stop();` on a timeline

Comment: My bad. I've changed the button to graphic. Your solution works well! Thank youu @BadFeelingAboutThis